# Spring Security - Is SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler broke?

Tags: spring, spring-security

TLDR:  Spring is destroying the current HTTP session when redirecting to the login page; this destroys the ability to navigate to the DefaultSavedRequest after login.  Why is this happening?

Details -
I am maintaining a legacy Spring application:

- Spring Core version 3.1.0
- Spring Security version 3.1.0

When trying to utilize SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler in my login configuration, it is not working.  Here is what seems to be happening:

- HTTP GET to secured resource: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/viewWorkOrder?workOrderNumber=315261`
- Spring correctly determines that I am not logged in and saves my request:

  ```
  DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/myapp/viewWorkOrder?workOrderNumber=315261]
  ```
- Spring correctly redirects to my login page:

  ```
  DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login.jsp at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
  ```
- Spring destroys the current session which effectively destroys the ability to later use the DefaultSavedRequest:

  ```
  DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionEventPublisher - Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@b25f027]
  ```

Why or what is causing the current session to be destroyed?

Here are the pertinent configuration details:

```
<bean id="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/postLogin" />
    <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="targetUrl" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
</bean>

<security:http auto-config="false">
    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
                         login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                         />

    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
```

- Note that the inclusion of `session-management` does not seem to affect the feature either way.

Comment: When exactly do you see, that your session is being destroyed? Right after redirection? Or after you enter your credentials and attempt to log in?

Comment: @Leffchik, right after redirection.  I will add another comment in a few as I try to isolate when it happens relative to the redirected controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing but in the interest of being a good citizen on stack overflow I thought I would share what I found.

After setting a breakpoint in the Spring HttpSessionEventPublisher to see if the stack might give me a clue, it certainly did.  Here is a screenshot:
[image]

You'll notice that login.jsp is on the stack.  Being new to this particular application, I hadn't really even suspected the JSP but here is what I found:

[image]

Obviously, removing this scriptlet solved my issue.  Now I just wonder why someone did it and what I broke in the process :)